# Include the word Appendix before A in table of contents

Tags: appendices, sharelatex, overleaf

Hi I am trying to add the word Appendix before the letter A or B in my toc.

I have been browsing through the solutions with little to no luck. When using \appendices I lose the functionality of the "subsection appendices" in the toc which I want to keep.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Images/umlogo.jpg}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\input{"Appendix.tex"}

\end{document}
```

And for the appendix file:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\appendixname~\thesubsection :}{0.5em}{}
\appendix 
\section*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\subsection{Pretests} 
\label{apx:pretests}

\subsection{Another appendix Subsection}
```

And this is how it appears:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use the `appendices` environment and the `title` and `titletoc` options:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc,page, title, titletoc]{appendix}


%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Images/umlogo.jpg}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\section{Pretests}
\label{apx:pretests}

\section{Another appendix Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oo thank you! One small question, how can I make the Appendix A and Appendix B appear as a subsection in the toc as I had before?